# Transfer data from local windows PC and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, file, ssh, transport

I want to transfer some files from my Windows PC to a Debian server. 
For usual I use FTP-Clients but I got a problem in hope that you can give me some advices. 
**Problem** 
I want to transfer some files on /etc/example and on this folder a normal user (f.eg user called tom) dont have rwx right on it - just r. To transfer some data there tom got the possibility to do "sudo su" while he is logged in as thom and then he got the rwx rights on this folder.

***Questions:***

1. Is there a possiblity with a FTP client to login with the sudo
   rights of this user? Because the password of the "first" root user I
   dont know.
2. Or is there another possibility to transfer files from windows PC
   like from /c:/users/example/dir to debian@IP:/dir/dir/dir.

I hope you guys know what I mean.

Kind regards
xcdsfda

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a FTP Client like Filezilla, copy your Windows files into /home/Tom (your home of your Debian)
Then, with Putty for instance, you can do a "sudo su -" then, you can write a "mv" or "cp" command.

It's not really recommended to give rights to /etc/folders to a normal user.

Comment: Yeah but can I move from Putty files from my local PC to the linux server?